# clone() has protected access - made public Object clone()

Tags: java, clone

I'm writing code to create an object, clone the object, then compare the two.

The object in question, Octagon, is an extension of an object GeometricObject

```
public class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Octagon>, Cloneable {
private double side;

public Octagon (double side){
    this.side = side;
}

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Octagon octClone = (Octagon)super.clone();
    return octClone;
}
```

In a file named Octagon.java

In another, TestOctagon.java, is my main method:

```
public class TestOctagon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeometricObject test = new Octagon(5); //create an Octagon with a side of 5
        System.out.println("Area is: "+test.getArea());
        System.out.println("Perimeter is: "+test.getPerimeter());

        Octagon copy = (Octagon)test.clone();


    }
}
```

The errors come in on the last line of the main method.

```
clone() has protected access in Object
```

I've tried renaming the clone method in Octagaon, say to cloneme, but then I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method cloneme()
location: variable test of type GeometricObject
```

I get the feeling the problem is because Octagon extends another object, maybe?

I really can't find any solution, and I've spent a good hour reading all the other clone() posts here.

Edit: It's required I use clone. I'm aware the general consensus is clone is borked.

Comment: You can't override a protected method to be public. In your `Octagon` class define it as `protected Object clone()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace

```
Octagon copy = (Octagon)test.clone();
```

with

```
Octagon copy = (Octagon)((Octagon)test).clone();
```

so that the called clone method is the one of your class.

Comment: Exactly what was needed. Thanks much. I needed to use something similar to call the custom `compareTo(Octagon o)` function as well `((Octagon)test).compareTo(copy);`  Seems ridiculous this isn't mentioned anywhere in my textbook.

Comment: clone is widely seen as badly designed, that's why you probably don't see it too much in textbooks.

Comment: Unfortunately the assignment from the text specifically required the use of clone. =\ Interesting read though, thanks.

Comment: hello, could you please explain why the need for a double cast?? I'm confused about it, thanx!

Comment: @Scaramouche The type of the `test` variable is `Object`. So it has to be casted in order to find the `clone` method. Then the returned type of `clone` is also `Object`, which means it has to be casted again to be assigned to the ̀copy` variable which is of type `Object`.

Answer (score 9):

You may write a copy-constructor:

```
public Octagon( Octagon right ){
    this.side = right.side;
}
```

And use it from the clone method:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new Octagon( this );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error and solved it by creating one public function inside class

```
public class Octagon { ....

    public Octagon copy() {
        try {
          return (Octagon) clone();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          return new Octagon();
        } 
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```