# thread-safe CopyOnWriteArrayList reverse iteration

Tags: java, collections

Consider the following code snippet:

```
private List<Listener<E>> listenerList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener<E>>();

public void addListener(Listener<E> listener) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeListener(Listener<E> listener) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listenerList.remove(listener);
    }
}

protected final void fireChangedForward(Event<E> event) {
    for (Listener<E> listener : listenerList) {
        listener.changed(event);
    }
}

protected final void fireChangedReversed(Event<E> event) {
    final ListIterator<Listener<E>> li = listenerList.listIterator(listenerList.size());
    while (li.hasPrevious()) {
        li.previous().changed(event);
    }
}
```

There is a listener list that can be modified and iterated.
I think the forward iteration (see method #fireChangedForward)
should be safe.
**The question is: is the reverse iteration (see method #fireChangedReversed) also safe in a multi-threaded environment?**
I doubt that, because there are two calls involved: #size and #listIterator.
**If it's not thread-safe, what is the most efficient way to implement #fireChangedReversed** under the following circumstances:

- optimize for traversal
- avoid usage of locking if possible
- avoid usage of javax.swing.event.EventListenerList
- prefer solution without usage of third-party lib, e.g. implementation in own code possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `listenerList.listIterator(listenerList.size())` is not thread-safe, for exactly the reason you suggested: the list could change size between the calls to `size()` and `listIterator()`, resulting in either the omission of an element from the iteration, or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown.

The best way to deal with this is to clone the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` before getting the iterator:

```
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener<E>> listenerList = ... ;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Listener<E>> copy = (List<Listener<E>>)listenerList.clone();
    ListIterator<Listener<E>> li = copy.listIterator(copy.size());
```

The clone makes a shallow copy of the list. In particular, the clone shares the internal array with the original. This isn't entirely obvious from the specification, which says merely

> Returns a shallow copy of this list.  (The elements themselves are not copied.)

(When I read this, I thought "Of course the elements aren't copied; this is a shallow copy!" What this really means is that neither the elements nor the array that contains them are copied.)

This is fairly inconvenient, including the lack of a covariant override of `clone()`, requiring an unchecked cast.

Some potential enhancements are discussed in [JDK-6821196](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6821196) and [JDK-8149509](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149509). The former bug also links to a [discussion](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2009-March/005926.html) of this issue on the concurrency-interest mailing list.

Comment: The code should read `(List<Listener<E>)((CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener<E>>)listenerList).clone()`, or else the code doesn't compile because it's looking for the `clone` method in `Object`, which is a protected method (I know that that's what you meant to write, but it took me a few minutes to find out what the error was).

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I  wouldn't have come up with this idea.
I think that's the best solution so far.

Comment: @MikaelF "Works for me." :-) I had assumed the declaration of `listenerList` was `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener<E>>` in Holger's original example, but you're right, it wasn't. I'll edit the snippet to make it clearer.

Comment: @Holger I missed it too! I only knew about it because I had previously dug up the old concurrency-interest thread.

Comment: @Stuart Marks Oh... My Intellij keeps underlining the `clone` in red and saying "'clone()' has protected access in java.lang.Object". The double cast is also what the accepted answer recommends in [clone() has protected access - made public Object clone()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044887/clone-has-protected-access-made-public-object-clone), and other similar questions. I don't know why it works for you and not for me... but good if it works for OP! thx

Comment: @StuartMarks I see, I didn't understand what the problem was, but now I get it, the double cast is only necessary if the list was declared as a `List` and not as its actual implementation. Smarter every day (hopefully)...

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do that is to call `#toArray` method and iterate over the array in reverse order.

Comment: Yes, that should be safe, but also requires an extra array copy for every iteration. I'll wait some time for more answers.

Comment: @Holger you can use reflection hacks to avoid array copy

Answer (score 1):

You could always just get a `ListIterator` and "fast-forward" to the end of the list as such:

```
final ListIterator<Listener<E>> li = listenerList.listIterator();
if (li.hasNext()) {
    do{
    li.next();
    } while (li.hasNext());
}
while (li.hasPrevious()) {
        li.previous().changed(event);
    }
```

**EDIT** I switched the quirky exception-handling of my previous answer for a do/while loop that places the cursor of the `ListIterator` after the last element, in order to be ready for the next `previous` call.

**RE-EDIT** As pointed out by @MikeFHay, a do/while loop on an iterator will throw a `NoSuchElementException` on an empty list. To prevent this from happening, I wrapped the do/while loop with `if (li.hasNext())`.

Comment: That code looks like it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the list is empty.