# Find the last element matching an expensive condition from a List, using Stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have an ordered `List` of roughly one million elements of which I'm looking for the last element that matches a specific condition, but the condition is heavy to compute so it's better if I start from the end instead. There are always roughly `log(n)` matching elements, with a minimum of 1.

I can do it manually:

```
List<Element> elements = ...;
Element element = null;
for (var it = elements.listIterator(elements.size()); it.hasPrevious(); ) {
  var candidate = it.previous();
  if (heavyConditionPredicate.test(candidate)) {
    element = candidate;
    break;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to write this using `Stream`s, so that the `heavyConditionPredicate` is not tested against each element of the list? If the heavyConditionPredicate would not have been so heavy to compute, I'd have used [alternative means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27547519/180719), but I'm not that lucky.

Note that `elements` can be any type of `List`, and the one I get doesn't necessarily implements `RandomAccess`, so accessing the list by their index might be costly as well.

Comment: Since you mentioned ordered list I would assume its sorted, you can use `Collections.binarySearch(list, 10); // assuming you are searching for 10.`

If it is not sorted, you can try sorting it and then perform binarySearch.

Comment: @Rupesh No, [it's not sorted: it's ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084146/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ordered-and-a-sorted-collection). Also, the ordering and the search criteria are not linked.

Comment: @Naman Would you clarify your usage of `IntStream` further? Why would it be appropriate?

Comment: Is the list implementation known / fixed / changeable ? Is it `RandomAccess`ible ?

Comment: @GPI My edit in the question and your comment happened at the same time. Please reload the question as your comment is answered.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire `IntStream.iterate(elements.size(), i -> i > 0, i -> i - 1)
                .filter(i -> heavyConditionPredicate.test(elements.get(i)))
                .findFirst();` is what I meant, but not sure about the thread safety when that's executed in parallel. This uses the API `IntStream iterate(int seed, IntPredicate hasNext, IntUnaryOperator next)`

Comment: @Naman I guessed that was the idea behind your last comment so I edited the question accordingly. The list is used only for its ordered property, therefore `List::get` might be costly.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire sure, not a straightforward way in Stream that I know of, might just be a custom `Spliterator` defined. Let's wait for better people to answer.

Comment: [How to get ordered stream from a list in reverse order in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29403614/2711488)

Comment: To whoever added the tag `java-8`, the code in the question is at least `java-10`... Please don't add tag unless they're actually correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guava's [`Lists::reverse`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse-java.util.List-) definitely helps here, as it's a view and it doesn't modify my list and it doesn't access elements by their index:

```
Lists.reverse(elements).stream()
  .filter(heavyConditionPredicate)
  .findFirst();
```

Comment: I wonder what the implementation of `Lists.reverse(elements)` is? I would definitely take a look at it as well.

Comment: @Naman I suppose, a simple wrapper with adapted `get` and `iterator`/`listIterator` methods. More wouldn’t be necessary. In the best case, it also has an adapted `spliterator` method, which would make `stream()` efficient. See also [How to get ordered stream from a list in reverse order in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29403614/2711488)…

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42239024/2711488) is also interesting…

Comment: @Naman Guava is open source, you're very welcome to [check the implementation online](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#L793).

Answer (score 2):

The disadvantage of the current implementation (as of Java 11) of `Stream` is that it doesn't allow to process items in the reverse order. You have to provide it the source with the specified order:

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
List<Element> reversedElements = new ArrayList<>(elements);
Collections.reverse(reversedElements);

Element element =  reversedElements.stream().filter(heavyConditionPredicate).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Another way is to use the advantage of the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) interface that offers [`Deque::descendingIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator()):

```
Deque<Element> elements = new ArrayDeque<>();
Iterator<Element> it = elements.descendingIterator()
```

With [`Deque::push`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html#push(E)) you can create a custom `StreamUtils` method reversing the passed `Stream` with no need of using an external library:

```
class StreamUtils {
    static <T> Stream<T> reverse(Stream<T> stream) {
        Deque<T> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        stream.forEach(deque::push);
        return deque.stream();
    }
}

...

Element element = StreamUtils.reverse(elements.stream())
    .filter(heavyConditionPredicate)
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but in both your solution you end up iterating the complete list once at least, which would be costly as mentioned in the question by OP.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't iterate through all the elements but only until the first element is qualified. `Stream::findFirst` is a short-circuiting operation. See: https://onlinegdb.com/By8AYHsPI

Comment: `Collections.reverse` or even your `StreamUtils.reverse` iterates on the list. So yes, there is a full iteration at least once. But iterating isn't costly: only `get(int)` can be costly. Iterating doesn't especially result in `get(int)` being called.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but I wasn't clean. The iteration with the costly predicate doesn't take necessarily all the elements, but the reversing the collection itself does (although it is cheap).