# Java is always pass by value so why am I getting reference when using Array.get(index)?

Tags: java, android

I was working on this bug in my application and saw something very weird:

```java
    selectedService = dataResponse.getServices().get(position);
    selectedService.setPrice(3000);
    dataResponse.getServices().get(position).getPrice(); // Returns 3000 which should be 0
```

Shouldn't the get method copy the object into `selectedService`? If not how to copy it?

Comment: It is pass by value. And you are getting the value of the reference to the object here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

Java is always pass-by-value, but that value itself is a reference. So if you call a method which alters data of that particular object, it is reflected to all methods retrieving data from that particular object.

A possible solution to this problem is to make [immutable types](https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object). There are classes which already implement this, for instance, all classes from the `java.time` package are immutable. All 'setters' of those classes return a fresh copy of the instance, with the specified value set. An example may be [`LocalDate::plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-).

---

Here is a little example of the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

Take a look at this code.

```
void main() {
    Dog myLittleDog = new Dog("Brutus");
    change(myLittleDog);
    System.out.println(myLittleDog.getName());
}

void change(Dog aDog) {
    aDog = new Dog("Jack");
}
```

What happens here? We pass our dog named "Brutus" to the `change` method. Within this method, we replace Brutus with a new Dog named "Jack". If we print the name of `myLittleDog`, what will be his name? Will it be "Jack"?
**The answer is no. The value of the reference to the dog is copied**, and is available within the `change` method under the name `aDog`. Both `myLittleDog` and `aDog` are referring to the same actual dog object in memory. But now the `change` method reassigns `aDog` with a `new` object. At this moment, the variables `myLittleDog` and `aDog` both refer to distinct objects. Once the `change` method exits, the variable `aDog` is unreachable and `Jack` is garbage collected. `myLittleDog` is still called "Brutus".

Conversely, this wouldn't be the case if Java was pass-by-reference. Then reassignment of `aDog` would also mean reassignment of `myLittleDog`.

See also: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

#### But then why is my `selectedService` still mutated?

Although values of references are copied when they are passed to methods, doesn't that mean that objects cannot change (that is, be modified). Suppose I give you a copy of my house key. You access my house and move the couch to the kitchen. Then if I enter my house, I will see that the couch has been moved. The reference value is copied, but everyone accessing the referenced object (the house), will see modifications to it.

Comment: So the only way to copy the object into another and make changes to it is to make a new object with the passed values? Is there an easier way with less boiler plate?

Comment: If you want to set the price on some object, but don't want to reflect this on the other, you *must* make a copy. This is often done with the builder pattern, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedService` here is a reference variable which points to whatever object you assign to it. While assigning `dataResponse.getServices().get(position)` to `selectedService` it appears as if you're assigning an object to it, however, what you're actually assigning is the reference to the original object.

As quoted on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/

> Unlike C++, in Java, if we use assignment operator then it will create a copy of reference variable and not the object

### To create a copy of the object

Use the `clone()` method to create a copy of the object as in

```
selectedService = (SelectedServiceClass) dataResponse.getServices().get(position).clone();
```

Comment: 'clone()' has protected access

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044887/clone-has-protected-access-made-public-object-clone
My bad, you can use clone if you have defined your own class and overridden it with a public method, and it still is risky. 

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java) which contains many methods for successful copying of an object