# Java Creating a Copy of a class

Tags: java

I want to copy an object, I tried clonable but failed.
To Implement minimax function I need to create a copy of the board class and check the best move

in my AIPlayer class

```
private int pickBestMove(Piece piece){
        int bestScore = 0;
        int bestCol = r.nextInt(board.NUM_OF_COLS);
        int[] validLocations = getValidLocations();
        for (int c = 0; c < validLocations.length; c++) {
             int row = board.findNextAvailableSpot(c);

             Board tempBoard = new BoardImpl(board.getBoardUI()); //Need to copy the board object here

             tempBoard.updateMove(c, row, piece);
             int score = scorePosition(tempBoard, piece);
             if(score > bestScore){
                 bestScore = score;
                 bestCol = c;
             }
        }
        System.out.println("Best Move is " + bestCol);
        return bestCol;
    }
```

Board is a interface, and BoardImplement is it's subclass

```
public interface Board {}
```

I tried the clonnable

```
public class BoardImpl implements Board, Cloneable {
//My other stuff
public BoardImpl clone() {
        try {
            BoardImpl clone = (BoardImpl) super.clone();
            // TODO: copy mutable state here, so the clone can't change the internals of the original
            return clone;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding this code to AIPlayer class (Mentioned above)

```
     Board tempBoard = (Board) board.clone();
```

but it failed,

> 'clone()' has protected access in 'java.lang.Object

What are the solution that I can do for this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044887/clone-has-protected-access-made-public-object-clone

Comment: `BoardImpl` may implement `Cloneable`, but what about `Board`?

Comment: You could always add a `Board copy();` method to your interface. The implementation can make use of `clone()`, or you could use a "copy constructor", or whatever.

Comment: Some terminology - 'clone' makes a copy of an instance (an object) of a particular class, it does not copy the class.

Comment: @Slaw, it worked after adding to interface